# How to split (A/B) test Magento product pages

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.7, ab-testing

I want to test different variations of product pages/layouts that I set up on Magento. It would be simple with a CMS page - but one cannot just create a new product. Customers should be able to buy exactly the same product, but enter on different pages.

NB: The google website optimizer thing (which I could never get working anyway) is apparantly dead now, replaced by content experiments via Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

CMS pages are simple A/B whereas product pages are multivariate. That means you get something ridiculous like 32 recipes for a product if you go and setup different descriptions, titles, pictures and whatever else. It all works just fine in 1.7 but there is some effort needed to follow the screencasts, test and tinker.

If you want A/B for products consider setting up two stores/website views in the backend, e.g. 'store A' and 'store B'. Now edit the index.php and set the store code to 'A' for people with even IP addresses and 'B' for people with odd IP addresses:

```
$mageRunCode=(ip2long(1 & $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? 'A' : 'B')
```

Comment: It's not a 'fair' test if testing segmentation method uses even/odd IP addresses. How would you ensure traffics are (approximately) evenly distributed?

Comment: Not so sure about the IP address idea since there is no guarantee of even distribution as @activars points out. Using different store/store views might work though. 

I'm much more interested in this multivariate testing with product pages in 1.7 though - where do you find these settings?

Answer (score 1):

Consider testing the layout change for only one product. The normal product page will be your control page (page "A")

If the price on the control page doesn't get updated frequently, simply create the challenger page (page B) as a static page somewhere on your server.

After you've done that setup the experiment in Analytics, add the experiment code to page A and you're done.